# Symfony generate cdn friendly asset url

Tags: php, symfony, twig, cdn

I have a symfony application that gets served by a cdn (eg. akamai) and I generate the asset url on the templates with:

```
{{ asset('myJs.js') }}
```

When I do I want to generate a url like (supposing that the site is served by `www.example.com`) :

> www.example.com/myJs.js?v=321321312312

Where the v parameter get a deployed version in order to force cdn (eg. akamai network) to cache me newer version. Is it a good way to dynamically generate the `v` parameter?

Comment: _“Where the v parameter get a deployed version in order to force cdn (eg. akamai network) to cache me newer version.”_ - what do you think this has to do with caching on the CDN side ...? This technique is commonly used to handle caching on the _client_ side ("cache buster", to prevent the client from serving outdated resources from cache.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append a hash to the file that is kept unique per version, you could either use the file modification time of that file or a hash. The best way could be to create a new Twig function versionedAsset() that uses the output of asset() and appends this hash to the generated URL

Answer (score -2):

src="www.example.com/myJs.js?v={{ random() }}"

Comment: This will add a random nonce to the URL with each and every new request, such that a CDN cannot cache this